# Map of Iterables - a generic way to add values to an iterable under the given key

Tags: scala

I can write the following for Vectors:

```
def add[K,V](map: Map[K,Vector[V]], key: K, values: Vector[V]): Map[K,Vector[V]] = {
  map + (key -> (map.getOrElse(key, Vector.empty) ++ values))
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> add(Map(1 -> Vector(1,2,3)), 1, Vector(4,5,6))
res1: Map[Int,Vector[Int]] = Map(1 -> Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

The code for Sets is almost identical:

```
def add[K,V](map: Map[K,Set[V]], key: K, values: Set[V]): Map[K,Set[V]] = {
  map + (key -> (map.getOrElse(key, Set.empty) ++ values))
}
```

How to make a single function that works for all Iterables? I tried to write it like this:

```
def add[K,V](map: Map[K,Iterable[V]], key: K, values: Iterable[V]): Map[K,Iterable[V]] = {
  map + (key -> (map.getOrElse(key, Iterable.empty) ++ values))
}
```

But in this case I lost type info:

```
scala> add(Map(1 -> Set(1,2,3)), 1, Set(4,5,6))
res4: Map[Int,Iterable[Int]] = Map(1 -> Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4))
```

I tried the following:

```
def add[K,V,I[_] <: Iterable[_]](map: Map[K,I[V]], key: K, values: I[V]): Map[K,I[V]] = {
  map + (key -> (map.get(key).map(_ ++ values).getOrElse(values)))
}
```

But it didn't compile:

> Cannot construct a collection of type That with elements of type Any based on a collection of type Repr. 
>   [error]     map + (key -> (map.get(key).map(_ ++ values).getOrElse(values)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `CanBuildFrom` to channel the type info about the used collection through the `++` call. See the overloads of `++` on `TraversableLike` for this.

The following works (not caring about details, like undefined keys).

```
def add[K,V,It <: TraversableLike[V,It]]
  (map: Map[K,It],k: K, vs: Traversable[V])
  (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[It,V,It])
  :Map[K,It] = 
    map + (k -> (map(k) ++ vs))
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the function without fully specified type signature? I can't imagine writing those types all the time.

Comment: @tokarev I had a second look and removed an unescessary type parameter. It should work now.

Comment: Scala awesomeness in action. I want to print this code on a t-shirt

Answer (score 2):

Ugly instanceof but works :)

```
def add[K,V,I[V] <: Iterable[V]](map: Map[K,I[V]], key: K, values: I[V]): Map[K,I[V]] = {
       val m: Map[K, Iterable[Any]] =  map + (key -> (map.get(key).map(_ ++ values.asInstanceOf[Iterable[V]]).getOrElse(values)))
       m.asInstanceOf[Map[K, I[V]]]
}
```

Results from scala console:

```
scala> def add[K,V,I[V] <: Iterable[V]](map: Map[K,I[V]], key: K, values: I[V]): Map[K,I[V]] = {
     |        val m: Map[K, Iterable[Any]] =  map + (key -> (map.get(key).map(_ ++ values.asInstanceOf[Iterable[V]]).getOrElse(values)))
     |        m.asInstanceOf[Map[K, I[V]]]
     | }
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
add: [K, V, I[V] <: Iterable[V]](map: Map[K,I[V]], key: K, values: I[V])Map[K,I[V]]

scala> add(Map(1 -> Vector(1,2,3)), 1, Vector(4,5,6))
res0: Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] = Map(1 -> Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

scala> add(Map(1 -> Set(1,2,3)), 1, Set(4,5,6))
res1: Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Map(1 -> Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4))
```

Comment: asInstanceOf is a code smell. +1 for a working solution though